# Avoid the translation of Abstract and References with UTF8 text

Tags: overleaf, utf8

I'm using the following packages for compiling UTF-8 text:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
```

Everything is working fine, except that latex automatically translates Abstract and References into my language. Specifically, Abstract becomes "Tóm Tắt Nội Dung" and References becomes "Tài Liệu Tham Khảo".

Is there a way to avoid the translation?

Comment: If you are writing the text in English, why do you have the document set to Vietnamese? Or do you wish to have the document in Vietnamese and only "Abstract" and "References" in English?

Comment: You didn't provide a complete document so it is hard to test, but you could try `\setlocalecaption{vietnamese}{abstract}{Abstract}` (and the same for `bib`) or `\renewcommand\vietnameseabstractname{Foo}` (and `\vietnamesebibname`). See the [babel manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf) section 1.15 for more information.

Comment: @Plergux The document is written in English for an international conference, but there are examples in Vietnamese.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you, I solved the problem myself (see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solve the above problem.
At the preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,vietnamese]{babel}
```

Then before the Abstract:

```
\selectlanguage{english}
```

Then after the Abstract:

```
\selectlanguage{vietnamese}
```

Finally, before the References:

```
\selectlanguage{english}
```